# html form submit handle response page with java

Tags: java, html, post, form-submit, http-post

I have a PayPal "pay now" button. If I click it - a POST request is sent to paypal and my current view gets redirected to the paypal site where I can pay.

In my application I want to do 2 Actions with one button - so I have to build the paypal button on my own in plain java and send a post request tp paypal.

Now I get a response page (html) but I have no idea how I can do the same redirect as done by clicking the button. I could display the page under my url (wich is not what I want) but I can't do the same redirect as the original button.

So my questions are:

- Why does this redirect really happen and how can I do this in plain java ( it's a JSF1.2 project)
- or is there an other solution to my problem?

thanks a lot!

k2

Comment: Can't you just call `sendRedirect()` on `HttpServletRespnse`? If not, could you be a little more clear about what you're looking for?

Comment: my main problem is, that I don't understandy why clicking the submit button in a form redirects to another page and I don't know the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was, that paypal offers payment via email. I took this link to work around this problem.